# Link excel data point by hyperlink

Tags: excel, charts, hyperlink

I have a graph with several data series on it, and in each series several points. I want to click on one point and have a jpeg or text file open. 
Is it possible to hyperlink a data point on a excel graph to a file outside the workbook? 
I know I can hyperlink the entire chart to another file but is it possible to link just one point to a file ? And can I do this for different points on the one graph, having them each link to different files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a hyperlink to a single point on an Excel chart.

You can write VBA code that will respond to clicking on a point, and jump to the link.

This would make a good topic for my blog; I've put it into the queue. I have some online content that you might be able to use to get started. The first link below is an overview of VBA chart events, the other two are lightly documented zipped Excel workbooks.

[Chart Events in Microsoft Excel](http://www.computorcompanion.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=221)

[Get Information about a Point on a Chart Sheet](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Zips/GetXYonaChartSheet.zip)

[Get Information about a Point in an Embedded Chart](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Zips/GetXYonAnyChart.zip)